# evaluating the integral $\int_{0}^\infty \frac{dx}{x^2+\cos x}$

Tags: calculus, integration, improper-integrals

The title explains everything. I've had this problem for a while now, but I've held off asking for help as I wanted to try doing it myself. I've tried all the basic techniques, including things like differentiating under the integral sign or complex substitutions, but I haven't had any progress getting towards a closed form solution. The most promising technique so far has been using various types of Taylor series (Taylor series of $\frac{1}{x}$ or $\cos x-x^2$) but that often results in overly complex series. I suspect some sort of solution may be possible through exploiting the evenness of the function, or residue theory, but I'm not too well versed in that. (sorry for any mistakes, I'm a bit new to MSE)
$$\int_{0}^\infty \frac{dx}{x^2+\cos x}$$

Comment: [A217732](http://oeis.org/A217732) gives the digits of this integral, and it doesn't seem like there is a closed form.

Comment: Beyond personal interest, is there a reason to suspect the integral has a closed form?

Comment: nope, a friend challenged me because they couldn't do it.

Comment: Find the poles ( numerically !!! ).

Answer (score 1):

*Just for the fun !*

Since your integrand contains a cosine, what about the *approximation*
$$\int_{0}^\infty \frac{dx}{x^2+\cos (x)}\sim\cos \left(\frac{29  }{694}\pi\right)+\cos \left(\frac{209  }{1170}\pi\right)$$ which is
$1.83801769497$ to be compared to the "exact" value
$1.8380176950$ that is to say an absolute error of $2.0\times 10^{-9}$%.

Answer (score 1):

Hint:

$$\int_0^\infty\dfrac{dx}{x^2+\cos x}=\int_0^\infty\dfrac{dx}{x^2\left(1+\dfrac{\cos x}{x^2}\right)}=\int_0^\infty\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty\dfrac{(-1)^n\cos^nx}{x^{2n+2}}~dx$$

which relates to https://mathworld.wolfram.com/SincFunction.html

Comment: Just out of curiosity : did you try ?

Comment: I have tried this, unfortunately I didn’t really get all that far. My guess would be to use power reduction formulas.